# How i can make a request for every token from a txt file in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, readlines

**I have a text  file called tokens.txt.**

Ex: 12463,4126,6343,6345.

**And i want to send a post request with each tokens and use multi threading.**

**For some reasons my code only gets the last token from the txt file and only uses that.**

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import time

url_list = [
    "https://www.google.com/api/"
]
file_lines = open("tokens.txt", "r").readlines()
for line in file_lines:
    tokens = {
        'Token':line.replace('/n','')
        }

def makerequest(url):
    while True:
        html = requests.post(url,stream=True, data=tokens)
        print(tokens)
        return html.content

start = time()

processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=200) as executor:
    for url in url_list:
        processes.append(executor.submit(makerequest, url))

for task in as_completed(processes):
    print(task.result())


print(f'Time taken: {time() - start}')
```

**How can i send for each token a request?**

Comment: Are the tokens comma separated or each  token in separate line? Can you add some samples of tokens. Don't post the original token here.

Comment: LLRGVO,P10U6M,8ECW1A @Kaushal

Comment: This is 1 token or 3 tokens?

Comment: Those are 3 tokens

Comment: Are the tokens comma separated or each token in separate line? It would be better if you add token file screenshot or details in the question. Still not able to understand your problem.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lTFCuyD here is an screenshot how the tokens are being put in the file. if i prin file_lines it prints ['1214152\n', '3254215\n', '3152515'] when i do for line in file_lines and after if i try to print the lines it only  prints the last one so i guess the problem it  is from he 'for line in file_lines'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `tokens = {"Token": <last_token>}`

Modify your code like this so that for each token one request can be sent.

```py
tokens = set() 
'''
<- You can use list also but in this case set is better  as it will ensure only 
one request for one token even if your tokens file contains duplicate line.
'''
url_list = [
    "https://www.google.com/api/"
]

tokens = set()
with open("tokens.txt", "r") as f:
    file_lines = f.readlines()
    for line in file_lines:
        tokens.add(line.strip())

token_data = {"Token": None}
def makerequest(url):
    for token in tokens:
        token_data["Token"] = token
        html = requests.post(url,stream=True, data=token_data)
        print(token)
        # do something with html here
        # don't return or break
```

Comment: It is still checking only for the last one for some  reasons.

Comment: It should have worked. I have moved the token_data dictionary to outside the function. Please check now and let me know if it works. Add some debug statements to check what is there in `tokens`,  `token_data` inside loop.

Comment: Sorry but the same thing it only gets the last one. [link[(https://imgur.com/a/lTFCuyD)

Comment: Please check this now. If it doesn't work, the put a `print(tokens)` and check if it contains 3 token or only 1.

Comment: Still only 1 for tokens.

Comment: It is working perfectly was my bad everything sorry for your time wasted trying to help a noobie :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

data = tokens

and at that point `tokens` is the assignment from the last line. If you want all tokens, you need to do something likej:

```
tokens = set()
for line file_lines:
     tokens.add(......)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the creation of the tokens dictionary - you loop ofer the tokens but you alway overwrite the value mapped to the  "Token" key.

Moreover there are a few bad practices in you code.

1. please be careful with the inline opening of files like you did

   file_lines = open("tokens.txt", "r").readlines()

Rather use it as a context manager

```
with open("tokens.txt", "r") as file:
    file_lines = file.readlines()
```

This makes sure that the file gets closed again after you read it - in your case you would need to make sure that the file gets closed (even in a crash etc.)

Secondly, avoid using global variables in functions. According to you code I assume that you want to query the different urls with each token - so the fucntion should accept both as arguments.  Respectively i would then create a list of combinations like

```
url_token_combs = [(url, token.strip()) for url in url_list for token in file_lines]
```

And finally, change your function to use the arguements handed to it rather than global ones like:

```
def makerequest(url_token ):
    url , token = url_token 
    html = requests.post(url,stream=True, data=token)
    return html.content
```

That allows you now to loop over your code with thread like:

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import time


def makerequest(url_token):
    url , token = url_token      
    html = requests.post(url,stream=True, data=tokens)
    print(tokens)
    return html.content


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time()
    url_list = [
    "https://www.google.com/api/"
    ]
    
    with  open("tokens.txt", "r") as file:
        file_lines = file.readlines()

    tokens = [{'Token':line.replace('/n','') }for line in file_lines ]

    url_tokens = [(url, token.strip()) for url in url_list for token in tokens]


    processes = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=200) as executor:
        for url_token in url_tokens:
            processes.append(executor.submit(makerequest, url_token))

    for task in as_completed(processes):
        print(task.result())


    print(f'Time taken: {time() - start}')
```

Comment: ```def makerequest(url_token):
        url , token      
        html = requests.post(url,stream=True, data=tokens)
        print(tokens)``` I think this part of the code should be after when the  token,url is defined because im geting the following errors: Undefined variable 'url',Undefined variable 'token',Undefined variable 'url' for line 7,8,9

Comment: yeah you are right - i was just dry coding here. I edited it so now it splits the tuple- Sorry my bad

Comment: I tried to fix it  but i couldn't, thanks for trying to help :)